# 400 bad request spring mvc controller with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc controller which takes **application/x-www-form-urlencoded data**. I am posting data to this controller from a html form and I have date fields in my form. My issue is that when I send null values for date I get error  **400 bad request**, when I specify date values it works fine.

Here is my spring MVC controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createorderform",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void createOrder(Model model,  @ModelAttribute Order order,HttpSession session){
    System.out.println("Inside Order Controller");  
    String CustomerName;
    System.out.println("hiiiii");
    Customer customer=null;
}
```

When I send null date values,  control is not coming inside mvc controller. How  can I allow my mvc controller to take null values?

Comment: Have you tested without `headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` ?

Comment: thanks for your response,ya i tested but it was not working, now i solved this issue by adding  **BindingResult errors**, its working fine now.

Comment: Great that you solve your problem. You should add your own solution as an answer, that way it will help other with same problem. I will upvote it. Don't forget to put the code and also a little explanation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `BindingResult`

```
public void createOrder(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute Order order, BindingResult errors,HttpSession session){


    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        // error handling code goes here.
        System.out.println("inside controlelr");
      }
```

`@Valid` tells spring controller to validate `Order`  object and
 `BindingResult` object holds the result of validation and binding the errors that may have occurred. `BindingResult` must come right after the model object